# Dynamic Filter Pagination Not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination, codeigniter-3

I have a list page with pagination that is working perfectly! It's good! I've seen a lot of posts here about getting pagination to work but I didn't see this same issue. If you think there's a post that will help, please direct there.

Now I moved on to a form on that same page, where the user can "filter" the results and that model/function returns the results to the same page. The pagination though for the search results isn't working.

My guess is that the Total_rows needs to change but I'm not sure if that's it.

For a broader view of whats going on, [heres my repository for it.](https://github.com/AnthonySDi/GiraffeHeros)

The Controller

```
public function searchGiraffe($offset = 0)
{
        // pagination configuration
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'MainForms/searchGiraffe/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->session->flashdata('resultcount');//$this->db->count_all('heroes');
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    // Init pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $GiraffeName = $_POST['name'];
        $GiraffeWork = $_POST['FieldsOfWork'];
        $GiraffeLocation = $_POST['location'];
        $GiraffeGender = $_POST['gender'];
        $GiraffeAge = $_POST['age'];
        $GiraffeOccupation = $_POST['occupation'];

        $data = array('h_name' => $GiraffeName,
                        'type_of_activism1' => $GiraffeWork,
                        'type_of_activism2' => $GiraffeWork,
                        'type_of_activism3' => $GiraffeWork,
                        'global_area_1' => $GiraffeLocation,
                        'global_area_2' => $GiraffeLocation,
                        'state_1' => $GiraffeLocation,
                        'state_2' => $GiraffeLocation,
                        'gender' => $GiraffeGender,
                        'age' => $GiraffeAge,
                        'occupation' => $GiraffeOccupation); // end of array

    $results = $this->Main_model->searchForGiraffe($data,$config['per_page'],$offset);
    //$count = $this->Main_model->countForGiraffe($data);

    if($results != null)
    {
        $data['g_heroes'] = $results;
        //$this->girafferesult($results);
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('heroes/find-giraffe',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');

    } //end if
    else
    {
        $data['g_heroes'] = 'error';
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('heroes/find-giraffe',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }

}  // end of SearchGiraffe()
```

The Model

```
public function searchForGiraffe($data,$limit = FALSE,$offset = FALSE){

    if($limit){

        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);

    }
    $search_for = array();

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(!empty($value) && $value != 'Select'){
            array_push($search_for, $key);

        }else{
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    $counter = 1;
    $filter = 'SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE ';

foreach($data as $key => $search){
    if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Select'){
        if($counter < count($search_for)){

            if($key == 'type_of_activism1' || $key == 'global_area_1'){

                $filter .= '(' . $key . '="' . $search . '" OR ';

            }else if($key == 'type_of_activism2' || $key == 'global_area_2' || $key == 'country_2' || $key == 'state_1' || $key == 'country_1'){

                $filter .= $key . '="' . $search . '" OR ';

            }else if($key == 'type_of_activism3'){

                $filter .= $key . '="' . $search . '") AND ';

            }else if($key == 'state_2'){

                $filter .= $key . '="' . $search . '") AND ';

            }
            else
            {

                $filter .= $key . '="' . $search . '" AND ';

            }

            $counter = $counter + 1;

        }else if($counter == 3 && $key == 'type_of_activism3'){

            $filter .= $key . '="' . $search . '")';

        }else{
            $filter .= $key . '="' . $search . '"';
        }
    }else{
        // do nothing
    }

} // end of foreach($data as $search)

    $result = $this->db->query($filter);
    $count = $result->num_rows();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('resultcount', $count);

    return($result->result());

} // end searchForGiraffe
```

For my final trick the view:

```
 <main id="find">
<?php 
    if(isset($g_heroes)){
        foreach($g_heroes as $row){
?>
<section class="giraffe">
    <div class="ghero">
        <a href="view-giraffe/<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
            <?php echo $row->h_name; ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="intro">
    <?php echo $row->blurb; ?>
    </div>


</section>
    <?php

        } // end of foreach

    } // end of else
echo '<div id="pagination">';
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination creates link system < 1 2 3 >

say you hav 30 rows total, 10 rows for each page 
if you set a filter you get 20 rows total thats 2 pages

When hou click on number "2" you are refreshig the post and you ar posting number 2 with out filter, so database servs you  page 2 of 3

you can use sessions to solve this

```
if ($this->input->get()) {
    $postdata = array(
                    'GiraffeName' =>   $_POST['name'],
                    'GiraffeWork' =>  $_POST['FieldsOfWork'],
                    'GiraffeLocation' => $_POST['location'],
                    'GiraffeGender' => $_POST['gender'],
                    'GiraffeAge' => $_POST['age'],
                    'GiraffeOccupation' =>  $_POST['occupation'],
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($postdata);
         }
                $GiraffeName = $this->session->userdata('GiraffeName');
                $GiraffeWork = $this->session->userdata('GiraffeWork');
                $GiraffeLocation = $this->session->userdata('GiraffeLocation');
                $GiraffeGender = $this->session->userdata('GiraffeGender');
                $GiraffeAge = $this->session->userdata('GiraffeAge');
                $GiraffeName = $this->session->userdata('GiraffeName');
                $GiraffeOccupation = $this->session->userdata('GiraffeOccupation');
```

Comment: I really appreciate it! I'll give that a shot!

I'll let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

While The previous answer helped me stop another issue.

I also figured out why the pagination wasn't working.

Because of the form and the database table I had to work with, I have a function that builds a Dynamic SELECT statement and then I run the SQL statement with $this->db-query().

This meant that my $this->db->limit() wasn't working, it works with codeigniters $this->db->get().

So I added a line to my model where I add the limit and offset to the SQL statement.

And now it's working!